# Handle press and hold hardware back button on windows phone using Coded UI Test

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, coded-ui-tests

I'm now working with Coded UI Test to make a automation testing framework for windows phone app. I can handle the press hardware back button by this `Device.HardwareButton.Back();` but I don't know how to press the hardware back button for seconds.

Answer (score 0):

As I know there is no direct solution for that, but there are other ways around.

If you want to kill the app, than fire the close method: `process.Close()` (`process` name is from `process = XamlWindow.Launch(appID);`)

If you want to change app, than launch it with an other `process2 = XamlWindow.Launch(appID2);` method.